# How to select multiple columns from DataFrame efficiently?

Tags: pandas

I'm writing something like Q-Learning on a DataFrame which consists of transitions. The data has the following columns:

`date, begin_time, begin_grid, end_time, end_grid, reward, [feature_columns]`

I'm using the below code to do mini-batch training:

```
for i in xrange(num_iter):

    idx = np.random.choice(N, batch_size)
    now_data = train_data.loc[idx]

    predicted_value = []
    for index, row in now_data.iterrows():
        action_state = row[["date", "end_time", "end_grid"]]
        #Can the next line be quicker?
        end_state_frame = train_data[(train_data["date"] == action_state["date"]) & (train_data["begin_grid"] == action_state["end_grid"]) & (train_data["begin_time"] == action_state["end_time"])]

        if len(end_state_frame) == 0:
            predicted_value.append(0.0)
        else:
            end_pred_values = model.predict(end_state_frame[feature_columns]).flatten()
            predicted_value.append(np.mean(end_pred_values))
```

In this code, I'm looking up on "date", "begin_time" and "begin_grid" repeatly. This code now is too slow to actually train the model. I'm wondering if I can do something to speed up the process (perhaps via setting index or grouping)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to group the data into batches where `date`, `end_time` and `end_grid` are equal?

Comment: @asongtoruin Yes, `train_data.groupby(["date", "begin_time", "begin_grid"])` then `get_group` can give my desired result. Is it the most efficient way?